# Validate input string

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I need to validate the input string of a text box whether it contains any numerical values in between the alphabetic letters and shows error as "it contains numerical value" in asp.net.

Comment: Do you limit it to only numeric or special character? You can use regular expressions

Comment: Have you tried using google and fed it the words "asp.net validate input string"? Plenty of results on *my* internet.

Comment: You have tried java script validation..!

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions

Comment: @ArunKumar don't accept a answer just to say thanks. I thought you needed a java script solution, but coder proposed a C# solution.

Comment: @Matten k whether we can use c# code in code behind file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
public bool IsAlpha(string strToCheck)
  {
    Regex objAlphaPattern=new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]");

    return !objAlphaPattern.IsMatch(strToCheck);
  }
Regards
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Regular Expression Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx).

Comment: I need it in java script dude.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to search for these things on the web yourself.

You need a `RegularExpressionValidator` as follows:

```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat=server display=dynamic
        controltovalidate="txtWhatever" 
        errormessage="Whatever cannot contain numbers." 
        validationexpression="[a-zA-Z]*" />
```

Comment: And i need it in java script dude. :)

Comment: @ArunKumar I'm not threatening you, but I can't understand why one posts a question here if it's faster to just google what you're searching for. The title of your question is what you need to find help on you preferred search engine. When you learning to write applications the web can be your best friend, but you need to get to know how to search certain things. If you'd not known what you want to achieve in terms of not knowing which technique to use, I'd understand. Why should others take time to answer your question if you hadn't took the time to try to solve the problem by yourself?

Comment: I searched it but due to the java script i cant able to create variables like other languages.. so little confusions.. that's y Matten. And here after i  try to solve this little issues by myself.